# Does inclusion give an injective homeomorphism $\pi[G \cap B(a, r),a] \to \pi[G, a]$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $G$ be a open, path connected subset of the plane and $a\in G$. Set $G' = G\cap B(a,r)$, where $B(a,r)$ is the open ball of center $a$ and radius $r$. Let $\gamma$ be a closed loop in $G'$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=a$. If $\gamma$ is homotopic to the constant path at $a$ in $G$, is it homotopic to the constant path in $G'$?

Obviously this is not true for e.g. $G$ subset of a sphere, so it being 2-dimensional manifold is not enough.

---

I think I can show this is true like this, but am very curious if there are other/simpler ways to do this, or I'm just wrong.

Lets assume that we can find a simple closed curve $C$ in $G'$ that encloses $\gamma$. Now using the Jordan–Schoenflies theorem there is a homeomorphism
$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(S^1) = C$. Now $D^2$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R^2}$ so there exists a continuous $r:\mathbb{R^2}\to D^2$, where $D^2$ is the closed disk of radius 1 centered at 1, with $r|D^2 = id_{D^2}$. Let $F$ be a homotopy from $\gamma$ to the constant path at $a$ in $G$. Then 
$$ h = f \circ r \circ f^{-1} \circ F$$ is a homotopy in $G'$.

I dont like this assumption about existence of the closed curve $C$ and I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Do you know about semi-locally simply connected spaces ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-locally_simply_connected

Comment: Yes, $G$ here is ofcourse semi-locally simply connected, its an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology. I dont see how that answers the question though, would you mind elaborating ?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't really have an answer, I just noticed that this was the underlying concept and I was not sure you knew about it (especially since you're a new user, so it's hard to know if you're a student or anything). It was just in case. :)

Comment: Well, thank you anyway :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that $\gamma$ is homotopically trivial in $G'$. It uses the same elements as your proof, i.e. Jordan-Schoenflies and a winding number argument.

We may assume $B(a,r) \not\subset G$ else we are done.

Let $h : D^2 \to G$ be a continuous map which extends $\gamma$.

By perturbing $h$, we may assume that it is in general position with respect to the circle $S_r = \partial \bar B(a,r)$, and so $h^{-1}(S_r)$ is a finite union of pairwise disjoint circles in the interior of $D^2$. Let the number of these circles equal $N$. I'll induct on $N$. If $N=0$, we're done.

Assuming $N > 0$, let $b_1,...,b_N$ be the components of $h^{-1}(S_r)$. These are boundaries of discs I'll denote $d_1,...,d_N$ (here the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem must be used).

Let $b_i$ be a component of $h^{-1}(S_r)$ which is innermost, meaning that $d_i$ contains no other $b_j$. It follows that either $h(d_i)$ is on the inside meaning $h(d_i) \subset \overline B(a,r)$, or it is on the outside meaning $h(d_i) \subset \mathbb{R}^2 - B(a,r)$.

Now we argue in two cases, depending on the degree $D$ of the map $h \, | \, b_i : b_i \to S_r$.

If $D=0$ then $h \, | \, b_i$ is homotopic to a constant within $S_r$. We can therefore redefine the map $h$ on $d_i$ to take values in $S_r$; let that redefined map be denoted $h'$. We can then perturb $h'$, moving $h'(d_i)$ entirely off of $S_r$, either pushing it to the inside of $S_r$ or to the outside of $S_r$ depending on whether $h(d_i)$ was on the outside or on the inside to begin with; let that perturbed map be $h''$. This map $h'' : D \to G$ is still a continuous extension of $\gamma$, and it is still in general position with respect to $S_r$, but the number of components of $(h'')^{-1}(S_r)$ is $N-1$, completing the induction.

If $D \ne 0$, I'll argue to one of a few contradictions. The map $h | b_i : b_i \to S_r$ must be surjective, and in particular it follows that $S_r \subset G$. If $h(d_i)$ is on the outside of $\bar B(a,r)$ then $h | b_i$ is homotopically nontrivial on the outside, which is absurd; this holds because the outside is an annulus and the inclusion of $S_r$ to this annulus is a homotopy equivalence (this is the step that fails in the 2-sphere). Thus $h(d_i)$ is on the inside of $\bar B(a,r)$. But now we can use a winding number argument, with the conclusion the map $h | d_i : d_i \to \bar B(a,r)$ must be surjective. It follows that $\bar B(a,r) \subset G$, contrary to our assumption.

Comment: I need few minutes to mull this over. In the meantime, what does "we may assume that it is in general position with respect to the circle " mean ?

Comment: Instead of general position I could have just said "we may assume it is transverse to the circle", in the sense of transversality that is explained in any differential topology textbook. To sidestep issues of smoothness I just used the more general terminology of "general position" instead of "transversality", although if I had added more words about approximating various maps by smooth maps then I would not have had to sidestep the issue at all.